# What is the error in python code?My error is "NameError: name 'OError' is not defined. Did you mean: 'OSError'

Tags: python

```
try:
    fh=open("testfile","r")
    fh.write("this is my test file for exception handling!!")
except OError:
    print("Error: can't find file or read data")
else:
    print("content written successfully")
```

NameError: name 'OError' is not defined. Did you mean: 'OSError'?

Comment: Like the sign says, its `OSError` not `OError`. Add that `S` and you're off to the rodeo.

Comment: change `OError` to `OSError` and bob is your uncle.

Answer (score 1):

Like the sign says, its [`OSError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError) not `OError`. A quick change to your code

```
try:
    fh=open("testfile","r")
    fh.write("this is my test file for exception handling!!")
except OSError as e:
    print("Error: can't find file or read data", type(e), e)
else:
    print("content written successfully")
```

and assuming the file exists, yields the output

```
Error: can't find file or read data <class 'io.UnsupportedOperation'> not writable
```

Which is odd because `io.UnsupportedOperation` was raised. That exception inherits from both `OSError` and `ValueError`. It gives you a more fine grained control of the exceptions.

This is a common situation. There are several fine-grained exceptions that inherit from OSError. If the file doesn't exist, you may get `FileNotFoundError`. As a programmer, you'll have to decide whether you want to catch all file errors in a single exception handler, or do more fine grained handling with the more specific errors.